# Sharepoint Excel Logic

Tags: excel-services, import, spreadsheet

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I would like to import onto Sharepoint. The import/export function is easy enough to use, however the math logic that four of the cells conduct in the Excel Spreadsheet does not transfer onto the Sharepoint site. For example, in the spreadsheet, there is a column "Date of Previous Flight" and a column "Days Since Last Flight". Excel is able to calculate "Days Since Last Flight" by subtracting "Date of Previous Flight" from the current date, but I cannot figure out how to get Sharepoint to do the same thing.

My desired end result is that users can go onto Sharepoint, input certain information, and Sharepoint does the in row math functions that my existing Excel spreadsheet can do. Is that possible? Is Sharepoint capable of calculating math?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can do calculations. But it cannot **import** the formulas.

You should import just columns with values, then create calculated columns in SharePoint where you can apply the desired formulas. Most simple Excel formulas can be done in SharePoint as well, using the same syntax.

SharePoint calculated formulas store the results in the list as values. If you have a calculation that involves the current date, this value will only be updated when the item is edited and saved. SharePoint does not allow calculations with [Today]. There are some hacks, but they don't work well.

If you need to see a dynamically updating view of the difference in days relative to the current date, you may want to look at a solution with Javascript / jQuery.